# How does the heat transfer in carnot cycle occur without a temperature difference between the reservoir and the fluid?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

If the temperature of reservoir in carnot cycle (Th) is the same of the fluid's temperature (Th also) then how the heat will transfer . I know that heat transfer from a hotter substance to a lower substance . but here the reservoir which transfers heat to the fluid has the same temperature of the fluid. So how will the transfer happen?

Comment: Do you have a reference to what you are asking about? Two isolated objects at thermal equilibrium will remain so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference, the temperature difference between the reservoir and the fluid in a real cycle can never actually be zero in order for heat transfer to occur. The Carnot cycle is an idealization in which the temperature difference approaches zero in the limit, making the heat transfer reversible an establishing an upper limit on the efficiency of any real cycle.

The Carnot cycle (or any reversible cycle) would be impractical because as the temperature difference decreases the rate of heat transfer decreases. As the temperature difference approaches zero, the time it takes to transfer heat becomes infinite, making the processes impractically slow.

Someone once said that if you put a Carnot engine in your car you would get fantastic fuel economy, but pedestrians would be quickly passing you by!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beautifully explained!

Comment: Bob is just a great person.

Comment: Thank you both for the kind words